# Element not intractable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to make a bot that plays a card game automatically, but I'm facing the following problem.
I want the bot to just drop random cards I don't care about winning or losing and I'm using this code:

```
while True:
    cards = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="face-up")

    for element in cards:
        try:
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
            break
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            # If the element is not clickable, continue to the next one
            print("couldn't click")
            continue
```

I used this method so when it can't click it, it tries another card if it's droppable it drops it, but the problem is that when I run the bot sometimes it just drops perfectly and so fast without any problems then for no reason, it just can't click it anymore (starts printing couldn't click) until I click the card manually then it continues, I don't know what is the problem or how can I solve it so if anyone faced something like this before please tell me how to solve it and I tried to change the way I click the element (card) like using  `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` or `element.click()` but still facing the same problem.

PS: while the bot is running and trying to click the cards and failing if I try to hover the mouse over the cards I can see the bot trying to hover over them but failing to click for some reason (even sometimes it clicks it when I manually hover over it, it rarely happens but maybe worth telling)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try:

1. wait for an element to be clickable (example from Java):

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
   WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
   element.click();
   ```
2. Or wait for the whole page is loaded (Java example)

   ```
   void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
            ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
   ```